# ViewDidAppear animation false

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidappear

I wanted to disable animated in viewDidAppear. I've set the code below but it shows me this error:

> "cannot assign to value: 'animated' is a 'let' constant"

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated = false)
}
```

Comment: The _ indicates that it is an anonymous argument. So just `super.viewDidAppear(false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a value to the `animated` parameter and parameters are `let` constants, hence the error.

If you simply want to pass `false` to `super.viewDidAppear` then simply pass `false`:

```
super.viewDidAppear(false)
```

There is no need to attempt to assign a value to the original `animated` property.